# test if a method behaves in a synchronized way

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, synchronized

The below code is a snippet outlining the objective of this unit test. The below demonstrates `createFile` only performing one task which is already known to be a thread-safe operation.

The idea therefore is more around the test than the actual operation; to prove beyond a shadow of a doubt, the **behavior** of a thread-safe method in that it behaves in a way that we have already proven historically.

```
public static final synchronized void createFile(final File file) throws IOException {
    file.createNewFile();
}

@Test
public void testCreateFileThreadSafety() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createFile(new File(i+".txt"));
                    new File(i+".txt").delete();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
        assertTrue(file.getParentFile().listFiles().length == 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

*What's happening now*: Thread gets created, file gets created, file gets deleted, thread dies, assert proves nothing and repeat

*What's expected*: Threads should all start and assert should ensure that only one file gets created at a time and that the other threads are waiting, not executing the method

**DOUBLE EDIT:**

What I really need is a refactor of the above unit test so that it does what it's supposed to do (as mentioned above)

Comment: I'm not really understanding the strategy. Why would checking that the current directory is empty, each time you start a thread creating and then deleting a file, test that your method is synchronized? And why synchronizing this method, since createNewFile() already *Atomically creates a new, empty file...* (quote from the javadoc)

Comment: Not going onto the details why this doesn't work; but pointing out conceptual weaknesses:

 - There is no point "proving" that the `synchronized` keyword works. As in: you also do not test that every primitive int value can hold 32 bits; and that there isn't one that only supports 31 bits. Because those are all elements *outside* of the scope of your application. In other words: you could/should trust such things. And even when there would be a bug in the JVM: expect it to be so subtle that *nothing* that you can easily think of would ever discover such problems.

Comment: - "Real" thread-safety is about preventing dead-locks, or race conditions that lead to data corruption or inconsistencies. Testing for that *is* possible to a certain degree; but then the test setup needs to be tailored to the specifics of your "code under test".

Comment: Long story short: your naive approach of having n threads executing a method and declaring that a test "it is thread save" is way too naive. In that sense: it is a nice exercise for you to learn about some things; but there isn't much *real* value in what you are doing.

Comment: What happens if your tests are run in a single threaded environment (which I have seen - AWS "cheap" servers are single threaded and frequently used for build servers), then you're not "testing" anything

Comment: @GhostCat in this project, it's up to the end-user to use an `ExecutorService` with a timeout or some other solution to ensure that no deadlocks occur. The method at this level won't be doing any of that...

Comment: If the goal of your test is to test somethong other than the posted code, then show what you really intend to test. As is, this test doesn't make sense, and there is no way to check if the method is synchronized or not, since it would do the exact same thing if it was not synchronized (since createNewFile is already thread-safe).

Comment: Voted to reopen. I think you can't prove it via JUnit test, but you could prove it by adding some code inside the method, e.g. incrementing a volatile static  counter, and checking that it increments only 1 at a time.

Comment: @Hooli I too think that JB is right. You see getting multi-threaded code **correct** is one of the great challenges in our business. If there would be a simply "works for everybody" approach to prove "multi-thread" correctness; be assured: we would all know about it.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm not doubting the complexity of the matter, I'm simply attempting to prove the behavior of a simple method using a unit test

Comment: BTW: check out https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage. It doesn't solve your problem right here, but it provides some JUnit support for testing asynchronous code.

Comment: Test your application. Not the platform. `synchronized` already works, and if it didn't you would have much bigger problems than this to solve, and so would everybody else, and the JDK version wouldn't have been released. They already test that. There is no point to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course for this very simple use case, it's quite silly, because the synchronized keyword is right there. But in general, if you want to test if a method is never called concurrently, you can throw in this:

```
static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();

public void knownNonThreadSafeMethod(final File file) throws IOException {
    int t = c.incrementAndGet();
    doSomething();   
    Thread.yield(); //try to force race conditions, remove in prod
    assert t == c.intValue();
}
```

If you'd use a simple int i.s.o. the AtomicInteger, compiler optimizations would remove the assertion.

```
static int c = 0;

public void knownNonThreadSafeMethod(final File file) throws IOException {
    int t = ++c;
    doSomething();   
    assert t == c; //smart-ass compiler will optimize to 'true'
}
```

With AtomicInteger, the value is guaranteed to be synchronised over all CPU's and all threads, and thus you'll detect any concurrent accesses.

I know it's not in a JUnit test, but I couldn't find any non-intrusive way to fix this. Maybe you can inject it via AspectJ?

Answer (score 1):

Create `File` subclass which overrides `createNewFile` method like this:

```
class TestFile extends File {

    private final AtomicBoolean isCreated = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private boolean isSynchronizationFailed = false;

    public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException {
        if (isCreated.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            // give other threads chance to get here
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            // cleanup
            isCreated.set(false);
        } else {
            isSynchronizationFailed = true;
        }
        return super.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

Pass instance of this class to your threads

Assert at the end your test that isSynchronizationFailed is false.

If two threads somehow enter createNewFile method at the same time, you will have isSynchronizationFailed variable set to true.

Comment: this is proof of concept, your comments are useful addition to it